# what is the size of the web3.eth.sign() result?

Tags: solidity, web3js, bytes

I am looking for a solution to emit a dynamique array of signature using event.
I thought that signature is a byte32 and it works, but I think is a 65 bytes.

so what is the exact size and how could I emit an event that contains an array of signatures ?

Comment: Have you read [this](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-accounts.html#sign)?

Comment: I read it. my question is how to emit an array of signatures.

Answer (score 1):

The important part of the signature consist of three fields

- `r` - String: First 32 bytes of the signature
- `s` - String: Next 32 bytes of the signature
- `v` - String: Recovery value + 27

Originally `v` was 1 byte, but since [EIP 155](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-155.md) it can have an arbitrary number of bytes. For more uses only 1 bit should be enough.

A common approach is to split the signature in those three fields r and s as bytes32 and v as byte and pass them as parameter.

Another option is to pass all of the together as an array of 65 bytes.

There's a new experimental ABI encoder that allows tuples as parameters, you might want to pass around a tuple with those fields.

Comment: I need a array of signatures so, an array of 65bytes array

Comment: Unfortunately there's no 65 bytes type. If you can use the experimental ABI encoder you can create an array of tuples<r,s,v>, or a bidimensional array of bytes (you have to enforce on the client each item is 65bytes). With the existing ABI the only option is to accept bytes and parse 'by hand' the parameters in your contract.

Comment: 'r' can be lesser than 32 bytes

Comment: @Mightywill Care to explain?

Comment: I dont know the math behind it but I use Ethereum cryptography in my project and sometimes (quite rare) I get R or S with 31 or 30 bytes length and these are correct values

Comment: @Mightywill It is possible for R or S to be shorter than 32 bytes but the specs says it is at most 32 bytes, so it is convenient to consider all cases. I think there's a trick to compress signatures to 64 bytes by leveranging the parity into R or S but I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: right, 32 is the max but it doesnt help much cause we cant simply store it as 32 bytes array cause u cant later determine whether trailing zeros are part of R or S component or  they are just for padding to 32 bytes - so u have to store additional info

Comment: @Mightywill I don't understand what are you trying to say. Storing R and S as 256 bits = 32 bytes is enough.

Comment: Ra = 0xXXXXXX.....YYYY0000 - 32 byte
Rb = 0xXXXXXX.....YYYY        - 30 bit

Ra != Rb, but if u store them both as 32 bit then you get the same byte sequence because u need to add two tralling zeros for Rb - and when u read it how to understand whether it 30 or 32 long?

Comment: @Mightywill In Ethereum it is common to assume R as S to be 256 bits integers, padded with zeros if needed. I suggest to create a new question, perhaps someone else has a better explanation.